# Are JSONB indexes slower than native indexes?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a large table (30M rows) which has ~10 `jsonb` B-tree indexes.

When I create a query using few conditions, the query is relatively fast.

When I add more conditions, especially one with a sparse `jsonb` index (e.g. an integer between 0 and 1,000,000), the query speed drops off dramatically.

I am wondering whether `jsonb` indexes are slower than native indexes? Would I expect a performance boost by switching to native columns rather than JSON?

**Table definition:**

```
id  integer 
type    text    
data    jsonb   
company_index   ARRAY   
exchange_index  ARRAY   
eligible boolean
```

**Example query:**

```
SELECT id, data, type 
FROM collection.bundles    
WHERE ( (ARRAY['.X'] && bundles.exchange_index)  AND   
type IN ('discussion') AND  
( ((data->>'sentiment_score')::bigint > 0 AND 
(data->'display_tweet'->'stocktwit'->'id') IS NOT NULL) )  AND  
(  eligible = true  )  AND  
((data->'display_tweet'->'stocktwit')->>'id')::bigint IS NULL )  
ORDER BY id DESC   
LIMIT 50
```

**Output:**

```
Limit  (cost=0.56..16197.56 rows=50 width=212) (actual time=31900.874..31900.874 rows=0 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=13713180 read=1267819 dirtied=34 written=713
  I/O Timings: read=7644.206 write=7.294
  ->  Index Scan using bundles2_id_desc_idx on bundles  (cost=0.56..2401044.17 rows=7412 width=212) (actual time=31900.871..31900.871 rows=0 loops=1)
        Filter: (eligible AND ('{.X}'::text[] && exchange_index) AND (type = 'discussion'::text) AND ((((data -> 'display_tweet'::text) -> 'stocktwit'::text) -> 'id'::text) IS NOT NULL) AND (((data ->> 'sentiment_score'::text))::bigint > 0) AND (((((data -> 'display_tweet'::text) -> 'stocktwit'::text) ->> 'id'::text))::bigint IS NULL))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 16093269
        Buffers: shared hit=13713180 read=1267819 dirtied=34 written=713
        I/O Timings: read=7644.206 write=7.294
Planning time: 0.366 ms
Execution time: 31900.909 ms
```

**Note:**
There are `jsonb` B-tree indexes on every `jsonb` condition used in this query. `exchange_index` and `company_index` have GIN indexes.

**UPDATE**
After Laurenz's changed query:

```
Limit  (cost=150634.15..150634.27 rows=50 width=211) (actual time=15925.828..15925.828 rows=0 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=1137490 read=680349 written=2
  I/O Timings: read=2896.702 write=0.038
  ->  Sort  (cost=150634.15..150652.53 rows=7352 width=211) (actual time=15925.827..15925.827 rows=0 loops=1)
        Sort Key: bundles.id DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
        Buffers: shared hit=1137490 read=680349 written=2
        I/O Timings: read=2896.702 write=0.038
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on bundles  (cost=56666.15..150316.40 rows=7352 width=211) (actual time=15925.816..15925.816 rows=0 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: (('{.X}'::text[] && exchange_index) AND (type = 'discussion'::text))
              Filter: (eligible AND ((((data -> 'display_tweet'::text) -> 'stocktwit'::text) -> 'id'::text) IS NOT NULL) AND (((data ->> 'sentiment_score'::text))::bigint > 0) AND (((((data -> 'display_tweet'::text) -> 'stocktwit'::text) ->> 'id'::text))::bigint IS NULL))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 273230
              Heap Blocks: exact=175975
              Buffers: shared hit=1137490 read=680349 written=2
              I/O Timings: read=2896.702 write=0.038
              ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=56666.15..56666.15 rows=23817 width=0) (actual time=1895.890..1895.890 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=37488 read=85559
                    I/O Timings: read=325.535
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on bundles2_exchange_index_ops_idx  (cost=0.00..6515.57 rows=863703 width=0) (actual time=218.690..218.690 rows=892669 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: ('{.X}'::text[] && exchange_index)
                          Buffers: shared hit=7 read=313
                          I/O Timings: read=1.458
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on bundles_eligible_idx  (cost=0.00..23561.74 rows=2476877 width=0) (actual time=436.719..436.719 rows=2569331 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (eligible = true)
                          Buffers: shared hit=37473
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on bundles2_type_idx  (cost=0.00..26582.83 rows=2706276 width=0) (actual time=1052.267..1052.267 rows=2794517 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (type = 'discussion'::text)
                          Buffers: shared hit=8 read=85246
                          I/O Timings: read=324.077
Planning time: 0.433 ms
Execution time: 15928.959 ms
```

Comment: This is too broad; you cannot answer a question like this generically. Please add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for some of your queries, then we can tell what is going on.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe added

Comment: Text, no images, please. And could you also add the table and index definition?

Comment: Thanks. And the definition of index `bundles2_id_desc_idx`?

Comment: Its a btree index using "id DESC" as the definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your fancy indexes are not used at all, so the problem is not if they are fast or not.

There are several things at play here:

1. Seeing the `dirtied` and the `written` pages during the index scan, I suspect that there are quite a lot of “dead tuples” in your table. When the index scan visits them and notices they are dead, it “kills” those index entries so that subsequent index scans don't have to repeat that work.

   If you repeat the query, you will probably notice that the number of blocks and the execution time becomes less.

   You can reduce that problem by running `VACUUM` on the table or making sure autovacuum processes the table often enough.
2. Your major problem, however, is that the `LIMIT` clause tempts PostgreSQL to use the following strategy:

   Since you only want 50 result rows in an order for which you have an index, just examine the table rows in index order and discard all rows that do not match the complicated condition until you have 50 results.

   Unfortunately it has to scan 16093319 rows until it has found its 50 hits. The rows at the “high `id`” end of the table don't match the condition. PostgreSQL does not know about that correlation.

   The solution is to discourage PostgreSQL from going down that route. The easiest way would be to drop all indexes on `id`, but given its name that is probably unfeasible.

   The other way is to keep PostgreSQL from “seeing” the `LIMIT` clause when it plans the scan:

   ```
   SELECT id, data, type
   FROM (SELECT id, data, type
         FROM collection.bundles
         WHERE /* all your complicated conditions */
         OFFSET 0) subquery
   ORDER BY id DESC
   LIMIT 50;
   ```

**Remark:** You didn't show your index definitions, but it sounds to be like you have quite a lot of them, possibly too many. Indexes are expensive, so make sure you define only those that give you a clear benefit.

Comment: Wow awesome, thank you. I'm going to try this now. Ye we have lots of indexes - the application is a SaaS dashboard which filters tweets, so I think its difficult to remove them unfortunately as we have lots of filtering options on the frontend

Comment: Query time halfed, thanks again! EXPLAIN posted above if you are interested. Still work to do but I think its more likely to be a database restructure...

Comment: One more thing, if I changed the table so that all of my complicated conditions were nice individual columns in a separate table (i.e. using a JOIN on id) would you *expect* to see a performance boost?... or impossible to say?

Comment: It looks like some of your conditions are not indexed properly. Hard to say anything - you still didn't tell me the `CREATE INDEX` statements.